# Shouldn't there be an induced current in a circuit?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

sorry for the newbie question we study the basis of physics, shouldn't there be an induced current in the circuit (if we keep turning on a switch and off) since the wire produces a change in a magnetic field?

[image]

Comment: "Back emf" and "self inductance" are relevant terms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is.  It's called Back EMF.   But it only happens for a brief moment after the switch is either open or closed.   A voltage is induced when a current CHANGES.   I.e. it's time-varying.   Steady state currents don't induce voltages.   The voltage coming out of your wall is AC...it's always changing so it always induces voltages In nearby Circuits ( this is how a transformer works).    The current from a battery is DC...no induced voltages occur due to DC